# JSF/Primefaces AJAX page rendered callback

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

My page layout (w/Primefaces) has a west, north and center layout panel which inclues all content. The center layout includes an iframe which each time a menu option is chosen (on the west panel), only the center content is updated (with Ajax).

While the page is rendering/loading I want to display a "loading gif" on one of the other panels. I have used the following code:

**xhtml segment**

```
 <p:ajaxStatus style="width:32px; height:32px;" id="ajaxStatusPanel">
            <f:facet name="start">
                <p:graphicImage value="/resources/img/progress.gif" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="complete">
                <h:outputText value="" />
            </f:facet>
    </p:ajaxStatus>
```

But this displays the loader briefly since it completes as soon as the ajax request is over. However the page loading/rendering may take a bit longer. Is there some way to provide a "page rendered" callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your actually loading content within an `iframe`, you can solve this problem by adding a little bit of javascript to your page, and especially the `onload`event handler.

**For example:**

```
<iframe id="navigation" src="#{layout.navigation}" onload="hideDialog()"
style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden; z-index: 999999;">
</iframe>
```

The code above will cause the `hideDialog()` function to be executed when the content within the `iframe` has finished loading.

The function you call (e.g. `hideDialog()`) can contain a reference to the dialog generated by JSF/primefaces and hide it.

```
<script>
function hideDialog()
{
if(statusDialog != undefined)
statusDialog.hide();
}
</script>
```

You may have to do some searching in the generated html+javascript to find the exact names/ids to use (in order to obtain a reference to the dialog).